# phpword wrong exports base64 images to docx file

Tags: php, docx, phpword

phpword wrong exports base64 images to docx file.

i have html with base64 images.
i want to export this html to docx file.
i use phpword.

```
$html = $obText->getHtml();

$pw = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

$section = $pw->addSection();

\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html, false, false);

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($pw, 'Word2007');

$objWriter->save($finalFilePath);
```

afther that - i have docx file with texts, tables, but without images.
why? whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

in source PHPOffice

`'img'       => array('Image', .....`

`preg_match('/data:image\/(\w+);base64,(.+)/', $src, $match);`

template must be similar

`<img src="data:image/gif;base64,--base64-coded-data---">`

Comment: dont understand. what u mean? i should change source code of PhpWord. Which class? note: i want to covert html to docx. my html already contains img tag with base64 code. And it works fine, when i output html to browser.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. In my case problem was, that html's tag img was invalid.
Reason was - that CRM , where i store data added special symbols of new line to base64 image data.

so i just made 
$html = str_replace("%0D%0A", "", $html);